# Creating and reading a calculation formula in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a Controller `Calculations` where I have a property called `Formula`. The main idea behind the `Calculation` is to perform operations using objects from other tables in the Database , here for instance `SetValues`.

**What I am trying to achieve**

I have a textbox for entering the Formula. I want to make sure that the variables used in the `Formula` are existing in the database. I can display the names of all the available rows in the table `SetValues`. I would like to make the values being displayed from the `Setvalues` click-able so that the value being clicked would be displayed on the textbox. I will keep a table with the mathematical operators as well which would also work in the same way. How can I make the TextBox for `Formula` the way I want? And how can I make the Names to be entered into the TextBox when clicked.

When the formula has been saved I want to use the formula to perform calculations based on the values of the `SetValues`(Assume  `SetValue` has properties  `Name` and `Values(int)`). I understand that I need to parse the Formula to perform the calculation which I have not yet tried, but could find other examples where the same has been performed. I have done something similar but with a Calculation string with numbers alone. I have not done something that would parse a formula and then assign values to it. Is it possible to achieve the parsing?

**Calculation View**

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.SetValues
{
    <p>@item.Name</p>
}

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CalculationName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CalculationName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CalculationFormula, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CalculationFormula, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
```

In a ViewBag I have passed the `SetValue` and the elements are displayed.

The Model classes and Controller are not relevant for the output I guess. But if it is required comment. Further details can be added.

**Update : adding Wireframe sample**

[image: Wireframe]

Comment: Nobody who could give at least suggestions on what i could possibly try?

Comment: what is the actual problem

Comment: The textbox for entering the Calculation formula should only contains variable names that are already present in the Database. I could list all the variable names, now I want to append those values to the Formula textbox when clicked.

Comment: Provide an simple example. the it will be more easy.

Comment: I was never successful to get it right. But i have the wireframe design of what I want to achieve. Would the image suffice?

Comment: hmm. then provide that...

Comment: Give me a minute please.

Comment: I have the list being populated just above my Formula textbox. But i want it to be clicked to be added to the Formula textBox.

Comment: You can use JavaScript/jQuery to trigger an event when there is a double click, then add the formula in the 'Formula' textbox. Do note that people can enter whatever they want in this, so you want to double check on the server side if it really is a valid formula from your database. See https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: I should generate unique id for each and every element in the list? I need the variables to be used for performing calculations.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the formula entered by the user? And can he combine multiple formulas, or?

Comment: with the above image i could tel you an example of a formula : `d_0 +a_sc*v_fix`. this could be a formula. All these values variables have different values in different parent classes. It should be possible to calculate the numeric value of the Calculation from the parent class.

Comment: Can you show an example of a parent class that holds the numeric values?

Comment: I have already mentioned it in the question . The class `SetVal` contains the numeric value. But there are no classes that will hold the value for the calculation. All the calculations should be executed during runtime. I am not sure id i answered your comment in the right way. is this what you asked.

Comment: As you can see on the other side of the wireframe the filters, the numeric value for the Calculation comes from the System class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your question regarding to adding the formula to the formula textbox when clicked. Here is some sample code. I use jQuery with a double click event.

**HTML**

```
<b>Formulas:</b><br/>
<i>Double click to append the formula.</i></br>
<select id="formulas" size="5">
    <option>d_0</option>
    <option>v_fix</option>
    <option>f_Fc</option>
    <option>a_sc</option>
</select>
<select id="operands" size="5">
    <option>+</option>
    <option>-</option>
    <option>*</option>
    <option>/</option>
</select>
<br/>
<span id="message" style="color: red"></span>
<hr/>
<b>Formula:</b><br/>
<textarea id="formula"></textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document.ready( function() {

    var formulas = $("#formulas");
    var formula = $("#formula");
    var operands = $("#operands");
    var message = $("#message");

    var expectFormula = true;

    formulas.dblclick(function() {

        if(expectFormula == true) {
            var currentFormula = formula.val();
            var appendFormula = formulas.val();
            var newFormula = (currentFormula + " " + appendFormula).trim();
            formula.val(newFormula);
            expectFormula = false;
            return;
        }

        message.html("Operand expected.");
    });

    operands.dblclick(function() {

        if(expectFormula == false) {
            var currentFormula = formula.val();
            var appendFormula = operands.val();
            var newFormula = (currentFormula + " " + appendFormula).trim();
            formula.val(newFormula);
            expectFormula = true;
            return;
        }

        message.html("Formula expected.");  
    });

});
```

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/L1r3xdvq/1/

I am by no means a JavaScript expert, but this should demonstrate on how to do this.

Do note that you have to double check the user input on the server, even though it is created with JavaScript, it is possible to enter whatever you want and send this as formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this in my code and then mark it as the answer. please give me like 10 mins to fit inside my code

Comment: I always have problems with rendering the Javascript in my View. I have added the Script in Head section. Should I be adding it somewhere else?

Comment: You need jQuery in your application. I usually add it to the end of the body, right before the `</body>` tag. You should also wrap the code in a `document ready event`. `$(document.ready(function() { alert(1); } );`. You will get an alert if it works (if you use this example). I also updated my answer.

Comment: OK. Now i am having the function being called. I tested it with an alert call.

Comment: Nice, now you can add the JS code from the fiddle, instead of the `alert(1);`.

Comment: Thank thanks thanks  a lot. I got it working. I added the `ìd =formula` to the div. Now I added it to the editor. It works. Now i should think how i could parse the values. But i will do it after getting the UI in the right way. Really thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it works! Now parsing the formula and calculating it, is an entire different endeavor. Good luck :)